# Ferry GraphQl and returning Stream of data for Query

Tags: flutter, graphql, ferry

I see that Query from Ferry returns Stream. Is it possible that it will smartly listen for updates? or does Stream for query always emit only a single value?

Comment: stream can emit n number of times, the question is vague, listening to what exactly? stream? data on the server?

Comment: I'm aware that Stream in Dart can emit many values, the question is specific for Ferry package and Stream response when executing GraphQl queries.